# MVC4 Redirect from ajax page redirecting the div (behaving like iframe)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, redirect

Hopefully I'll get this across articulately.

I'm using ajaxform in an MVC4 page to send a CSV file chosen using

```
        $(function () {

        function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            $('#loadedData').html(responseText);
        }
        var options = {
            target: "#loadedData",
            success: showResponse
        };

        $("#form0").ajaxForm(options);
    });
```

The file and the mapped headings are then sent to another Controller Action which does the processing and I have a RedirectToAction("Index") which I wanted to redirect the whole page on completion.

The strange thing is, the div that is the target of my ajaxform result is being redirected to the index. So I end up with the Upload page in the browser and the #loadedData having the contents of the index view.

Its as if the div is acting as an iFrame (which it isn't). I've tried various redirects and the workaround I have but would rather avoid is to have a specific view that will redirect the page at client side explicitly.

**points to note:** I'm bound by corporate policy to use the build install of IE8, the drag drop etc is all working as is the ajax upload of the file for preparsing so thats fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working exactly as designed.  jQuery's AJAX handler is getting the redirect and handling it, and loading the resulting data in `loadingData` as you instructed it to do.

If you want the actual *page* to redirect, you need to handle that yourself.  You're better off returning a JSON result from the ajaxForm handler that either denotes success, which makes your JS redirect to a given page, or have your handler return JSON that denotes the redirect URL.

Option 1:

```
{ "success": true }
```

Option 2:

```
{ "success": true, "redirect": "/Index" }
```

Use a `JsonResult` for your Action handler.  Create a simple Model/ViewModel and pass it to the JsonResult type and you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for adjusting my understanding. it didn't register with me that the ajaxform was active for both my posts, I just didn't think it through properly.